# Image not rendering in cell component in React Native

Tags: react-native, image, expo, mobile-development

Doing a react native project for creating a food app. The code doesnt throw any errors. But the images simply dont render.

```
function HomeScreen(){
    return(
      <ScrollView>
        <TableView>
          <Section header='' separatorTintColor={"black"} >
           
            <HomeScreenCell title="Bollywood Foods" tagline="Indian, Asian, Spicy" eta="15" imageUri={require('./assets/mollysbar.jpg')}/>
            
           
           
          </Section>
        </TableView>
       
        
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
```

The function defining these props.

```
const HomeScreenCell = ({title, tagline, eta, imageUri}) => {
  return (
    <Cell 
    cellStyle='Basic'
    cellContentView={

      
      
        <View style={{ height: 290, position: 'relative'}}>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={imageUri}/>
          <Text style={{position: 'absolute',fontSize: 18,backgroundColor: 'transparent', fontWeight: 'bold', top:20 }}>{title}</Text>
          <Text style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 200, right: -300, backgroundColor: 'dimgray', color: 'ivory', padding: 5, borderRadius: 5 }}>
            {eta} mins
          </Text>
          <Text style={{position: 'absolute', fontSize: 16, color: 'grey', top: 200 }}>{tagline}</Text>
        </View>
      
    }
    
    highlightColor="gray"
    
    />

  );
  };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI8Gj.jpg)

I did try sorting out the code. Trying to move the image to different directories. Tried with different images. Adjusted the image style. But to no avail. :(

Comment: Did you define image `width` and `height`  inside `styles.image`

Comment: Yes I had .  image:{
    flex:1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    marginBottom:10,
  },
});

Comment: You need to have  image:{ flex:1, resizeMode: 'cover', marginBottom:10 ,  width:400,height:400} fro example

Comment: Height and Width values are required to display a remote image